# App install banner not works

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, web-applications, manifest

I have been working on a web app. A week ago i have added the [**App install banner**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/app-install-banners/?hl=en) feature from chrome web tutorials.it works well while testing it from chrome developer tools Application tab.in mobile it works well when i enabled the **Bypass user engagement checks** flag, but the popup is not showing after i disabled the **Bypass user engagement checks** flag.

tried Clearing the chrome data, visited the website continuously 10 times still the popup is not shown up.

The banner is prompted on second visit on different day.in the documentation it shows the banner will be displayed after individual visits with time span differnet of 5 mins.In my case its not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing myself with that feature and faced similar issues.

Try disabling ad block?